# Select text using a link multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I found the following code online which works well. I would like to use this on multiple elements on the same page and do not know how to do this. I can get the first  to work but not the second.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Javascript:

```
    function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection
    ;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

document.onclick = function(e) {    
    if (e.target.className === 'select') {
        SelectText('some_text');
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<span id ='some_text'>Text to select </span><span class='select'>select</span>

<span id ='more_text'>More text to select</span><span class='select'>select</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call function with same parameter.

`SelectText('some_text');`

"Text to select" will be selected no matter what class="select" you click.

Try this code:

```
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
    , text = doc.getElementById(element)
    , range, selection;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

document.onclick = function(e) {    
    if (e.target.className === 'select') {
        SelectText(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
    }
};
```

And change the HTML:

```
<span id ='some_text'>Text to select </span><span class='select' data-id="some_text">select</span>

<span id ='more_text'>More text to select</span><span class='select' data-id="more_text">select</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not working though unfortunately as the second span select the first span text.

Comment: Ignore my previous message. I had a typo. Works great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a special attribute to each span with the id of the element you want to select:

```
//JS
SelectText(e.target.attributes["select"].value);
//HTML
<span class='select' select="some_text">select</span>
<span class='select' select="more_text">select</span>
```

Or, if the order of the elements is always similar and is not likely to change, you can retrieve the previous sibling:

```
SelectText(e.target.previousSibling.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can do:

```
SelectText(e.target.previousSibling.id);
```